# Can a Dhampir Sword Bard use their fangs as a spellcasting focus?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, bard, natural-weapon, spellcasting-focus

A Dhampir's fanged bite is considered a simple melee weapon,

> **Vampiric Bite**. Your fanged bite is a natural weapon, which counts as a simple melee weapon with which you are proficient.

At level 3, the Sword Bard can use a simple melee weapon as a spellcasting focus:

> If you’re proficient with a simple or martial melee weapon, you can use it as a spellcasting focus for your bard spells.

Does the Dhampir Sword Bard's fanged bite qualify as a spellcasting focus?

If so, do they still require a free hand to use it as a focus?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate, as this question has been asked before about a different feature that uses the exact same text: “counts as a simple melee weapon with which you are proficient.”

Comment: The idea of a Bard touching their own tooth while trying to verbalize a Suggestion is now stuck in my head and it's hilarious.

Comment: @Erik as far as I understand, you are always considered touching yourself. That doesn't sound good, dammit. But it would make an interesting question.

Comment: Dark greetings everyone, dark greetings...